# Can't get recursive fadeIn,toggle,show to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, fadein

I'm trying to get a recursive `fadeIn`, `show` or `toggle` function to work properly, I can't see where is the error.

**HTML:**

```
<table id="myTable"></table>​
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    var showMenu = function (i, callback) {
            if (i > 10) {
                //stop
                return;
            } else {
                $('#myTable').append('<tr id="method_1' + i + '" style="display: none;"><th><label for="id_CAM_1">CMethod (CAM):</label></th><td><select name="CAM_1_' + i + '" id="id_1_' + i + '">        <option value="2">2- canopy</option>        <option value="9">9-canop</option></select>      </td></tr>');
                $('#method_1' + i).fadeIn('1000', showMenu(i + 1, showMenu));
            }
        }
    showMenu(2, showMenu);
})
```

The problem is that the effect is not being called in the callback, but all at once instead.

[Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/5NZPL/22/)

Comment: HTML attributes should be double-quoted.

Comment: noted, does not seem to fix it anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your fadeIn callback, you have to provide a function, not a function call (what you're doing). I would suggest:

```
$('#method_1'+i).fadeIn('1000', function () {
    showMenu(i+1,showMenu);
});
```

I think that should do it...

Here is a jsFiddle that demonstrates my change: http://jsfiddle.net/mAETY/1/

Comment: This behavior doesn't actually fade in though.. It just iterates over the items

Comment: What are you talking about? How does it not fade in? I just updated my answer with a jsfiddle that clearly works, using the code I provided...

Comment: I'm using IE8, maybe that is the issue

Comment: I just opened your fiddle and it doesn't fade in

Comment: I just tested in IE7, IE8, and IE9 and they all work fine. And I just looked at your jsFiddle and it's like the exact same as mine...so I don't know how it doesn't work for you...

Answer (score 2):

That's because you do not provide a callback to `fadeIn`, but rather call `showMenu` again immediately (before even `.fadeIn()`).

Fix this by actually providing a function to call instead of calling one on the spot:

```
 $('#method_1'+i).fadeIn('1000',function() { showMenu(i+1,showMenu) });
```

[**See in in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/k6SpA/).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(function(){

    var menu = (function(i){
         var $this =  {
             show: function(){
                  if(i++ > 10) return;
 $('#myTable').append('<tr id="method_1'+i+'" style="display: none;"><th><label for="id_CAM_1">CMethod (CAM):</label></th><td><select name="CAM_1_'+i+'" id="id_1_'+i+'">        <option value="2">2- canopy</option>        <option value="9">9-canop</option></select>      </td></tr>');


                  $('#method_1'+i).fadeIn('1000',$this.show); 

             }
         }
             return $this;
    });

    menu(0).show();

});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just remove the id and style from the table row and encapsulate the table row in a dive then add the id and style to it. It will work.

```
$(function(){

    var showMenu = function (i,callback){

      if (i>10){
        //stop
         return;
      }else{
         $('#myTable').append('
         <div id="method_1'+i+'" style="display: none;">
         <tr><th><label for="id_CAM_1">CMethod (CAM):</label></th><td><select name="CAM_1_'+i+'" id="id_1_'+i+'">        <option value="2">2- canopy</option>        <option value="9">9-canop</option></select>      </td></tr>
         </div>');

          $('#method_1'+i).fadeIn('1000', function () {     showMenu(i+1,showMenu); });               
      }
    }

    showMenu(2,showMenu);                                                           

})
```

**EDIT**

http://jsfiddle.net/weightlossexp/V3gDE/

Comment: I just tested this... Works perfect

Comment: This is very interesting behavior, can anyone explain why this works?

Comment: although Im not sure it matters anymore

Comment: your jsfiddle isn't the same as the code you provided...the callback to fadeIn is wrong